# how to make validation by using jquery steps and stops steps if no valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, tabstop

I have a payment form with jquery steps and jquery validation.

Here is the pen to illustrate the form https://codepen.io/lee-min/pen/vYGXGOY

I add on this but all next steps button cannot click

```
form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
return form.valid();

onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {

    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
    return form.valid(); },
```

this is my validation

```
$('#specialNumber').on('keyup', function (e) {
if (!this.value.match(/^(6|8|10|12)$/)) {       
    $(this).addClass('error-color'); // adding error class
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('error-color'); // remove error class
} });
```

Comment: Had you write your validation code on StepChaning? Try to find here "http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples"

Comment: yes, my validation is written in StepChaning